# Why doesn't the query on my story chooser work?

Tags: rally

I am attempting to create a Chooser that will enable selection of a Work Product assigned to the selected iteration.

The Chooser created by the code below only displays "There is nothing to display." even though I know there are several User Stories in the iteration.

Commenting out the query specification results in a Chooser that displays 200 Work Products from the entire history of the Project.

```
    function addChooser() {
        var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                             '__PROJECT_OID__',
                             '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                             '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

        var iterDropdown;
        var wpChooser;

        function onWPSelected(wpChooser, eventArgs) {
        var selectedItem = eventArgs.selectedItem;

        console.log(selectedItem);
        };

        function displayChooser(iterSelectedName) {
        var chooserConfig = {
            type : 'HierarchicalRequirement',
            title : 'Choose a Work Product',
            fetch : 'FormattedID,Name',
            width : 600
        };

        chooserConfig.query = '(Iteration.Name = "' + iterSelectedName + '")';

        wpChooser = new rally.sdk.ui.Chooser(chooserConfig, rallyDataSource);
        wpChooser.display(onWPSelected);
        };

        function onIterationSelected(dropdown, eventArgs) {
        var selectedName = dropdown.getSelectedName();

        displayChooser(selectedName);
        };

        function showDropdown() {
        var iterConfig = {
            rememberSelection : false
        };
        iterDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.IterationDropdown(iterConfig, rallyDataSource);
        iterDropdown.display(document.getElementById('iterationDiv'), onIterationSelected);
        };

        //Load initial data
        showDropdown();
        };

    rally.addOnLoad(addChooser);
```

I have tried adding the Iteration to the Chooser's fetch attribute, but that has no impact.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the request sent to Rally (in Chrome debugger or Firebug) you'll notice it has an extra set of parens:

```
((Iteration.Name = "My Iteraton"))
```

Additionally the following error string is returned from the Wsapi:

```
[Could not parse: Unknown operator ")"]
```

Looks like this is a bug in our documentation for [Chooser](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/chooser).  There are some inconsistencies around when and when not to use parens with the query parameter depending on which component you are using.  In this case you shouldn't:

```
chooserConfig.query = 'Iteration.Name = "' + iterSelectedName + '"';
```

Note you can also use the [IterationDropdown's getQueryFromSelected](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/iteration-dropdown) method:

```
chooserConfig.query = iterDropdown.getQueryFromSelected();
```

I'll make sure the documentation gets updated to not use parens in the example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion.  I figured it was a formatting issue, but I couldn't find the correct combination.  In the end I used the IterationDropdown's getQueryFromSelected.  It seemed the more elegant solution.  Thanks again.